# How to remove from autorun postgresql in xubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, postgresql

There is no postgresql option in the autorun menu, but it starts when the system starts.
Searches have failed.
Can you help?

Comment: I disagree its being a duplicate because 1) OP doesn't know it's a service 2) If the answer is removed, the answers in the linked question aren't sufficient

Comment: @Anwar if OP doesn't know it's a service, then any answer is simply guessing at a solution.

Comment: @muru Guessing sometimes may not work. It worked here won't make it a duplicate. The service could be named as `pg` too!

Comment: @Anwar it could, but is it?

Comment: @muru Yes, only after you knew the answer. That's why it isn't a duplicate

Comment: @Anwar no, I don't need the answer to know that, since a look at the package file listing of postgresql tells me that. I'm not sure why you think I VTC'd because of the answer, I don't care about it. The dupe is the canonical post on enabling and disabling services. If the question where about what the postgresql service is named, I wouldn't be VTCing. But it isn't.

Comment: @muru It's OP that needed to know the answer. And I'm sure OP wouldn'be be helped if it was closed as a duplicate of that one. That one is a question about enabling and disabling _process_ of services for different Ubuntu versions. It's not a canonical question for every process that starts and happen to be a service and needs disabling

Comment: Eh? I'm not sure what distinction you're drawing there, but I'm not interested in continuing this discussion. I see the motivation and I'm not inclined to continue.

Comment: @Anwar: Linking this question to muru's suggestion imho is equivalent to this: "How can I do X?" – "X is a special case of Y. Here's how you can do Y."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

postgresql starts as a systemd service. To stop autorun of it, simply execute this command in terminal

```
sudo systemctl disable postgresql
```

This should disable autorun of postgresql upon boot. If you want to re-enable it, use

```
sudo systemctl enable postgresql
```

command.

Comment: Oh, I see. The answer is by you, hence all the angst.

Comment: @muru maybe or may not be. That's not a point here. I request you not to draw such conclusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a service not a autorun program for your user you have to disable it via systemctl.

`sudo systemctl disable postgresql.service`

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo update-rc.d postgresql disable` command to remove from autorun.